# Unable to start debugging

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

When I am trying to debug my c program in visual code, I am getting the following error. Could you please check and guide.[image]

Below I have attached launch.json[image]

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint before you started the program? It seems that it started and already terminated with an error.

Comment: What does your `launch.json` file look like?

Comment: Attached Launch.json, Check now @lololololol

Comment: Your character set is `unicode utf-8`, right?  Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69619818/vscode-unable-to-start-debugging-unexpected-gdb-output-from-the-command-envi

Comment: This didnt helped.